# Alternative input to LaTex newcommand

Tags: latex

Is there an alternative way to enter multiple arguments to LaTex newcommand constructions? I have defined

```
\newcommand{\nuc}[2]{\ensuremath{^{\text{#1}}\text{#2}}}
```

and I would like to call the command through

```
\nuc{12,C}
```

and not

```
\nuc{12}{C}.
```

I have created other commands with even more arguments and my poor pinky can't handle all the brackets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use plain TeX `\def`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\nuc}[1]{\nuc@#1\@nil}
\newcommand*{\nuc@}{}
\protected\def\nuc@#1,#2\@nil{\ensuremath{^{\text{#1}}\text{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will like it.

```
\def\nuc #1,#2.{\ensuremath{^{\text{#1}}\text{#2}}}
```

Sample of using:

```
\nuc 12,C.
```

Note. Use the dot at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I like to praise perltex for defining complicated functions. This isn't complicated, but you can extend it quite impressively.

```
%myfile.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{perltex}

\perlnewcommand{\commafrac}[1]{
  $input = shift;
  @inputs = split(/,/, $input);
  return "\\ensuremath{\\frac{$inputs[0]}{$inputs[1]}}";
}

\begin{document}
One half is $\commafrac{1,2}$.
\end{document}
```

Compile with `perltex --latex=pdflatex myfile.tex`. I know that \frac wasn't your example, but I find it a visually appealing one.

Answer (score -1):

As fas as I know  `\nuc{12}{c}` is the only way. If you don't want to put all the "}{"s, let the editor do it. Write `\nuc{12,c}` first, then replace all commas with "}{"s.

Comment: Unfortunately replacing commas with }{ will cause problems in the rest of the text. Now perhaps using ",," would work or some other string that isn't likely to exist elsewhere in the text.